# Can someone explain correct answer about this message queue question?

Tags: magento2, message-queue, rabbit-mq

what is the correct answer in this question?

> An Architect is working to implement Adobe Commerce into a pre-built
> ecosystem in a company. Communication between different company
> domains uses event-driven design and is driven via AMQP protocol with
> using RabbitMQ. The Architect needs to establish the data flow between
> the ERP system and Adobe Commerce. The ERP system stores only customer
> data excluding customer addresses. The role of Adobe Commerce is to
> provide Customer Address data to the enterprise ecosystem. Primary
> Customer data should not be changed from Adobe Commerce side; it
> should only be updated by messages data from ERP. Which three AMQP
> configurations should be considered to meet these requirements?
> (Choose three).

- A. Create a queue_consumer.xml and communication.xml configuration
  files for Customer data messages
- B. Create a queue_publisher.xml configuration file for Customer data
  messages
- C. Create a queue_publisher.xml configuration file for Customer
  Address messages
- D. Create a queue_topology.xml configuration file for Customer
  Address messages
- E. Create a queue_topology.xml configuration file for Customer data
  messages
- F. Create a queue_consumer.xml and communication.xml configuration
  files for Customer Address messages

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is
A,C,D
analyzed the given options:

A. Create a queue_consumer.xml and communication.xml configuration files for Customer data messages
This option involves creating configuration files for consuming Customer data messages from the ERP system. It's relevant to the requirement of updating customer data from the ERP system.

C. Create a queue_publisher.xml configuration file for Customer Address messages
This option involves creating a configuration file for publishing Customer Address messages. This aligns with the requirement of providing Customer Address data from Adobe Commerce to the ecosystem.

D. Create a queue_topology.xml configuration file for Customer Address messages.

The queue_topology.xml file is used to define the topology of your messaging system. It essentially describes the structure of queues, exchanges, and bindings between them. This file defines how messages flow between different components of your system. It specifies how queues are connected to exchanges and how messages are routed based on certain criteria.